# Jquery finding div on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought I was doing this correctly but can not seem to get it working and and searching for answers.  What I am trying to do is find and retrieve the text from a div that is dynamically created upon the returned information from a ajax call.  On the success I am creating a list of divs and dropping numbers in.  What I'd like to happen is when that div is clicked on get the value but I'm not getting anything. Here is how the div's are created.

```
$(".optionsBox").prepend("<div id='newList'>Navigate Pages </div>");
for (var i = 1; i <= ml; i++) {
    $("#newList").append("<div class='paging'>"+ i + "</div>");
}
```

I've tried:

```
$('.paging').click(function(){ 
     var number = $this.text();
}); 

$('.paging').on('click',function(){
     var num = $this.text();
});
```

I've also looked at .closest and even .find When logging to the console everything is blank.

I am obviusly making this harder than it should be.

Comment: That is the value of `$this`, do you mean `$(this)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you using .append ... you can use

```
$(".optionsBox").on('click', '.paging', function(){
  var number = parseInt($(this).text() , 10);
});
```

take a look at [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$(this)` (the jQuery object constructed with the current element)  instead of `this` and use Jquery `.text()` to get the text inside current div with class `paging` clicked :

```
$('body').on('click', '.paging', function(){
     var number = $(this).text();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(".optionsBox").prepend("<div id='newList'>Navigate Pages </div>");
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  $("#newList").append("<div class='paging'>"+ i + "</div>");
}

$('body').on('click', '.paging', function(){
    var number = $(this).text();
  
    $('.result').text('Number ' + number + ' clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="optionsBox"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```